# TV guide written in PHP - problems with datetime() and database functions

Tags: php, development-environment, cron

I'm creating a TV Guide which lists programmes coming up (and on some listings, previous airings from the past), with all data stored in a database. It runs in PHP, my version being 5.28 (upgrading to 5.30 or 6 soon).

Below is a script which works (note the field airdate is stored as DATETIME in the database):

[Disclaimer: The script isn't mine, but a generic one I downloaded, and modified to suit my own needs.]

---

```
<? //connect to mysql //change user and password to your mySQL name and password
mysql_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD"); 
//select which database you want to edit
mysql_select_db("tvguide1"); 
//select the table
$result = mysql_query("select * from epdata3 order by airdate LIMIT 20;");
//grab all the content
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
 //the format is $variable = $r["nameofmysqlcolumn"];
 //modify these to match your mysql table columns
$programme=$r["programme"];
$channel=$r["channel"];
#$airdate = strtotime($r['airdate']);
  $airdate = strtotime($r['airdate']);
  $now = strtotime("NOW");
 $currentYear = date("Y", $now);
$yearOfDateFromDatabase = date("Y", $airdate);
 if($yearOfDateFromDatabase == $currentYear)
$dateFormat = "F jS - g:ia"; // dateFormat = 24 December
else
$dateFormat = "F jS, Y - g:ia"; // dateFormat = 01 January 2010
$currentTime = date("g:ia", $airdate); // format of "Y" gives four digit year ie 
2009 not 09
$airdateFormatted = date($dateFormat, $airdate);
$sDate = date("F dS, Y - g:ia",$airdate);
$episode=$r["episode"];
$setreminder=$r["setreminder"];
echo "<tr><td><b>$programme</b></td><td>showing on $channel</td>";
echo "<td>$airdateFormatted</td><td>$episode</td><td>$setreminder</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

That displays all the episodes coming up, and if there's any coming up the next year, it displays them with the year, like this:

> TV Programme showing next on Channel1 December 30th, 2009 - 6:00pm "Episode 1 - Photosynthesis" Set Reminder
>
> TV Programme showing next on Channel1 January 6th - 2:45pm "Episode 2 - Behind the Music" Set Reminder
> TV Programme showing next on Channel1 January 7th - 8:00pm "Ultimate Car Crimes" Set Reminder

However, what I would like it to do is remove certain records after a period of time has expired (but that would have to be set somewhere in the script, since programme lengths vary) rather than me manually deleting them from the database. Some programmes are 30 minutes long, others 60 minutes... lengths vary, basically.

What I would like it to do is this (notice that the first listing does not show the date as it is the current date.):

> TV Programme showing next on Channel1 6:00pm "CCTV Cities - Wigan" Set Reminder
>
> TV Programme showing next on Channel1 January 9th - 2:45pm "Roman Empire - A History of its People" Set Reminder
>
> TV Programme showing next on Channel1 January 10th - 8:00pm "Celebrity 100 Worst Moments" Set Reminder

but I don't know how to configure it to do this with PHP or the date() function. It works fine with the dates, and showing them.
I don't have access to cron jobs since this is on a localhost Apache installation on Windows Vista Home Edition.

If anyone could help me figure this out it would be much appreciated - all help is much appreciated.

I haven't put this as a live site, since it's "in development hell" right now, and I want to get things right as much as possible.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question? How to display dates differently based on current date or what?

Comment: It's PHP 5.2.8 and 5.3.0. PHP 6 is too far away for you to even care about it ;-)

Comment: Do you mind sharing ur data sources for the tv guide?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MySQL can literally handle millions of records - why bother deleting when you can archive..? Just don't show the archived records.

for listing future records instead of this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from epdata3 order by airdate LIMIT 20;");
```

I would suggest something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from epdata3 WHERE airdate > '$today' ORDER BY airdate LIMIT 20;");
```

For a gig listing page I years ago also added a delete algorythm fearing the db could get 'full' - but regretted it later...

Comment: "ASC" is missing after airdate imho

Comment: Thanks, that works! Solved one problem!
In response to Tatu, it <i>is</i> to display the date differently based on the current date - i.e. to show it like this for the current date's record:
<blockquote>
TV Programme showing next on Channel1 6:00pm "CCTV Cities - Wigan" Set Reminder 
</blockquote>

Notice how the current date isn't shown - that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

It was inspired by this - http://library.digiguide.com/lib/programmenextshowing/House-238308 (the date automatically disappears on the day itself when the programme airs).

Thank you for your advice so far!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I assume you are asking how you can select only episodes from today or future, and how to format the date so that when the episode is airing today, show only the date.

Here's a revised version of your code that can handle both of those:

```
<?php
//connect to mysql
mysql_connect("localhost","root","PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db("tvguide1"); 

// Select only results for today and future
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM epdata3 WHERE airdate >= CURDATE() ORDER BY airdate ASC LIMIT 20;");

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $programme   = $r["programme"];
    $channel     = $r["channel"];
    $airdate     = strtotime($r['airdate']);
    $episode     = $r["episode"];
    $setreminder = $r["setreminder"];
    $now         = time();

    if(date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d', $airdate)) {
        // Same date, show only time
        $dateFormat = 'g:ia';
    } elseif(date('Y') == date('Y', $airdate)) {
        // Same year, show date without year
        $dateFormat = 'F jS - g:ia';
    } else {
        // Other cases, show full date
        $dateFormat = 'F jS, Y - g:ia';
    }

    $airdateFormatted = date($dateFormat, $airdate);

    echo "<tr><td><b>$programme</b></td><td>showing on $channel</td>";
    echo "<td>$airdateFormatted</td><td>$episode</td><td>$setreminder</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Tatu, thanks for that! Worked like a charm, simple and effective coding.

One more thing... how would I get it to not show records once the current time has passed (as a test I inserted a programme that aired at 8:30am today, and it showed up despite the fact it was hours ago! )

One more thing... how do I get my pagination to work for multiple records like this?
http://pastebin.com/fccf3500 has the current script.

Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: The answer to your first question is simple: in the SQL query, instead of `CURDATE()`, use `NOW()`. `CURDATE()` compares date, whereas `NOW()` compares to the current time also. To your second question: you'd better read some turials on creating pagination or create a new question for that. And remember; if you found this answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

```
function reldate ($time) {
    $now = time();
    $cmp_fmt = '%Y%m%d';
    if (strftime($cmp_fmt, $time) == strftime($cmp_fmt, $now)) {
        $out_fmt = '%I:%M %P';
    } else {
        $day = strftime('%e', $time);
        if (preg_match('/([^1]1|^1)$/', $day)) {
            $day_suffix = 'st';
        } elseif (preg_match('/([^1]2|^2)$/', $day)) {
            $day_suffix = 'nd';
        } elseif (preg_match('/([^1]3|^3)$/', $day)) {
            $day_suffix = 'rd';
        } else {
            $day_suffix = 'th';
        }
        $out_fmt = '%B %e' . $day_suffix . ' - %I:%M %P';
    }

    return strftime($out_fmt, $time);
}
```