# Pagination script for TV guide project

Tags: php, pagination

Thank you to all who helped me with my last question ([TV guide written in PHP - problems with datetime() and database functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031451/tv-guide-written-in-php-problems-with-datetime-and-database-functions/2031673#2031673)) - however, what I'm trying to do is paginate the results now, as seen here:
http://pastebin.com/fccf3500

Is there a way to get this to work as a pagination script?

Comment: Please take some time first reading the FAQ page for StackOverflow. You seem to be answering your own questions with more questions, not upvoting or marking answers accepted, commenting on wrong posts, registering twice etc. Get yourself accustomed to this site, that way you'll get help easier. And *don't* forget to upvote answers and mark one of them accepted - people only help you if there's something in it for them also.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I haven't' gained any reputation yet though.

Comment: @AN Other: There you go, 20 reputation points. Welcome to StackOverflow! =)

Comment: -1, for all of Tatu's reasons.  Also for a very unhelpful description of this new problem

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PEAR's Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) package.